# How to open tab matched with url id?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url, tabs

I'm trying to find out how i can open tabs that is matched with url id. How can i make the tab open it self when the url matches the tab menu?

I have tried to console log it but cant figure out how to do it.

```
  var i, tabContent, tablinks;
  tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabContent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabContent.length; i++) {
    tabContent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" activeTab", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(rocketName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " activeTab";

  parent.location.hash = rocketName;

}


//open tab by dedault
   // document.getElementById("default").click();
```

I expect to open tabs with matched url. example if i click on a category on a page it will send me to the page with the tabs and open the correct one.

Comment: You need to implement login inside document onload, fetch the param name and then set appropriate class to the elements.

Comment: Thank  you for you help. can you show me ?

Comment: You need to give a little more info about your URL params and are you using jQuery?

Comment: https://github.com/Christianschrodahl/tabfix/tree/master/microsite
here is everything. 
i want it to work. so i can click on the section inside homepage and open the right tab matched with the link on mission page. 
i hope you can help. sorry for late awnser.